# How to trigger Wallpaperservice.enigine class using alarm manager. (I don't want to use RTC_Wakeup)

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-wallpaper

I am developing a wallpaper app. Which create a folder in external storage if that folder don't exist. User set time interval. Then app will set wallpaper (if not empty) from that folder in interval provided by user.

1. `File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"imagesWallpaper");`

   ```
   if(!dir.isDirectory())
       dir.mkdirs();
   ```

It is not creating folder i exteral memory don,t know why

2.I triggered wallpaper service but i don,t know why it is not starting WallpaperEngine class .please help.

**WallpaperMainActivity:**

```
public class WallpaperMainActivity extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    public long interval = 0;
    File[] wallpaperImages = null;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wall_paper_manager);

    File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"imagesWallpaper");

    if(!dir.isDirectory())
        dir.mkdirs();


        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
            {
            long time =Integer.valueOf((String) findViewById(checkedId).getTag());
            interval = time*60000;
            scheduleAlarm();    
            }
        });

    }

    public void scheduleAlarm() 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperMainActivity.this, WallpaperSrvc.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(WallpaperMainActivity.this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 10*1000, interval, pintent);
    }
}
```

**WallpaperSrvc and WallpaperEngine classes:**

```
public class WallpaperSrvc extends WallpaperService {
        File[] wallpaperImages = null;
        int count = 0;
        Bitmap tmp = null;
        //Drawable drawable;

        @Override
        public Engine onCreateEngine() {

            return new WallpaperEngine();
        }

        public class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {
            private boolean mVisible = true;

            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
                mVisible = visible;
                 if (visible)
                 {
                    getImage();
                    draw();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    stopSelf();// stop the wallpaper
                 }
                super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
            }

            @Override
            public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                    float xOffsetStep, float yOffsetStep, int xPixelOffset,
                    int yPixelOffset) {
                draw();
                super.onOffsetsChanged(xOffset, yOffset, xOffsetStep, yOffsetStep,
                        xPixelOffset, yPixelOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {

                super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                getImage();
                super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
                mVisible = false;
                stopSelf();
                 // stop the wallaperservice
            }


        }

        public  void getImage()
        {
            File dir= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+"imagesWallpaper");

            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
            else
                wallpaperImages = dir. listFiles();

            if(count < wallpaperImages.length)
            {
                this.tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(wallpaperImages[count].getAbsolutePath());
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
                this.tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(wallpaperImages[count].getAbsolutePath());
            }

        };
        public void draw() {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try
            {
                //Bitmap wallpaper = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(tmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        };
    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name=".WallpaperSrvc"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="wallpaper_service"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/mywallpaper" >
            </meta-data>
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".WallpaperMainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>   
         <receiver android:name=".WallpaperSrvc"/>       
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Main Activity Layout:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="@string/Discription"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/one_day"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oneminute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 minute" 
            android:tag="1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/thirty_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="30 minutes"
            android:tag="30"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/one_hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 hour"
            android:tag="60"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/two_hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 hours"
            android:tag="120"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/six_hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6 hours" 
            android:tag="360"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tvlv_hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="12 hours"
            android:tag="720"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/one_day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 day"
            android:tag="1440"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/three_days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3 days"
            android:tag="4320"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oneweek"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="week"
            android:tag="10080"/>
    </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**res/xml/mywallpaper.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wallpaper 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:description="@string/wallpaper_description"  
  android:settingsActivity="com.wallpaper.WallpaperMainActivity"/>
```

Comment: can you post some code of what you have tried.

Comment: no worries, just edit your question and use the editor's code section to input code.

Comment: have you declared the service in your `AndroidManifest` & requested the correct permissions?

Comment: @Blundell can you help me now in this code?

Comment: @ user370305  need help in this issue.

what i have done wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use write external storage permission. thats why its not creating your directory.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

add this along with your Alarm and Wallpaper persmissions in your manifest

Comment: Thanks @humblebee for solving issue 1.
any help for issue 2?
will be gratefull

Comment: @Aown Raza can you answer this?